# MacBook air 2015 doesn't wake from suspend

Tags: graphic-drivers, drivers, suspend, macbook

I just installed Eos on my MacBook air early 2015 and am very impressed so far. But when I close the lid or press the power button to suspend the laptop it doesn't wake up. It also takes a very long time to start again because it has to be restarted completely. I read in the stack exchange that it could be something with NVIDIA drivers, but as far as I'm aware the MBA has onboard Intel graphics